# Rotating around axis in d3js

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to create a rotation controller to rotate a rectangle around its center point in d3js. I've managed to scrape something together using several resources, but when I try to rotate around its center point the rectangle will 'fly' away.

Here's a JSFiddle showing the rotation:

```
self.attr('transform', 
        'translate(' + curX + ', ' + curY + ') rotate(' + newRotation + ')'
      );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/skoq1eww/1/, and here's one showing it fly away when trying to rotate around the rectangle's center point:

```
self.attr('transform', 
    'translate(' + curX + ', ' + curY + ') rotate(' + newRotation + ', 50, 25)'
  );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/skoq1eww/3/.

I've found some related stackoverflow posts relating to rotating around an axis and they advise adding in the origin coords to the rotation as I've done above, but for some reason I can't seem to get it to work. I've been racking my brain on this for a few hours and I'm completely stuck. Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to the curX and curY values changing, which I hadn't noticed before. I'm not entirely sure why those values are changing as I'm not changing the translate of the object.

Comment: To add to my confusion neither values change in the first JSFiddle example...

Comment: Ugly fix (not a good solution) for anyone else who encounters this problem: https://jsfiddle.net/skoq1eww/5/